# VBA: Word Frequency Array

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm attempting to compute the frequency of terms within a collection of variable length strings.  The context is descriptions in an Access database.  Would prefer to keep the solution in VBA.  Delimiter is " " (space) character.  Special chars will be removed in advance.

My first pass feels a bit brute force; I suspect a much more efficient approach is possible.

Here is what I am doing currently for a SINGLE string, which is providing the result I expect:

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()

    Dim myCol As Collection
    Dim myArray() As String
    Dim strArray As Variant
    Dim strDescr, strTerm, strMsg As String
    Dim i, j As Integer

    Set myCol = New Collection

    strDescr = "This is just a test only a test test test"

    myArray = Split(strDescr, " ")

    For Each strArray In myArray
        On Error Resume Next
        myCol.Add strArray, CStr(strArray)
    Next strArray

    For i = 1 To myCol.Count
        strTerm = myCol(i)
        j = 0
        For Each strArray In myArray
            If strArray = strTerm Then j = j + 1
        Next strArray
        'placeholder        
        strMsg = strMsg & strTerm & " | " & j & Chr(10) & Chr(13)
    Next i

    'placeholder
    'save results into a table
    MsgBox strMsg

End Sub
```

Sample Result:

[image: sample result]

Next, I need to expand this approach to step thru a recordset, to keep appending words to the array and collection.  Recordsets can be large, 30K records, descr are 30-60 chars.

Questions:

1. How do I append to an array for each row in a recordset?
2. Will this approach fail as I scale the number of records?
3. A better approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your instinct is correct - this is pretty much brute force, so it won't scale well. And yes, there is a better approach - I'd use a Scripting.Dictionary instead of the `Collection`.  It allows 2 things that a `Collection` doesn't: First, you can check for the existence of a key without relying on the error handler, (and simply store the counts in the `Dictionary` itself). Second, you can retrieve the Keys array to easily extract your results.

Your code would translate into something more like this:

```
'Requires a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.
Private Sub Command0_Click()
    Dim counts As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim word As Variant
    Dim desc As String

    desc = "This is just a test only a test test test"

    For Each word In Split(LCase$(desc), " ")
        If Not counts.Exists(word) Then
            counts.Add word, 1
        Else
            counts.Item(word) = counts.Item(word) + 1
        End If
    Next

    For Each word In counts.Keys
        Debug.Print word, counts(word)
    Next
End Sub
```

As far as your last question, "how do I append to an array for each row in a recordset?" - all you need to do is to loop through the recordset and add them into the same `Dictionary`. Then you can simply retrieve the total counts when you're done.

Comment: Comintern, This is excellent.  Thanks for the suggested approach!